# Exception handling in JmsTemplate send

Tags: java, exception, jms, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

I want to send a large string message (3-5 MB) with jmstemplate (with activemq jms broker). In the middle of sending the message, i shutdowned my broker; Why i can't catch throwed exception in catch(Exception e)? What should i do to handle this exception?

```
public class MessageSenderServiceImpl implements MessageSenderService
{
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void sendMessage(final String messageContent, final String destination) throws SendingMessageException
    {
        try
        {
            jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator()
            {
                @Override
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException
                {
                    BytesMessage byteMessage = session.createBytesMessage();
                    try
                    {
                        byteMessage.writeBytes(messageContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        return byteMessage;
                    } 
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new JMSException(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });         
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new SendingMessageException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate)
    {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exception do you get? What's in the log file?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I am seeing something similar. Is it possible JmsTemplate did not throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but it could be because Spring's JmsTemplate re-throws exceptions as JmsException which is a Runtime exception, so you need to catch Throwable to actually catch it.

Comment: RuntimeException extends Exception, i think.

Comment: yes, you are right - please disregard my comment - I was looking at this post and missed that you already are catching top Exception: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?95919-Exception-handling-while-doing-a-jmsTemplate-send

Comment: Its not recommended to catch Exception its to abstract. I give you a point for giving me the name of the exception :) JmsException

Comment: This is mostly wrong.  `JmsException` is not a subclass of `RuntimeException`.  I suggest the following guideline for catching `Throwable`: if you're not sure whether or not you should catch `Throwable`, you shouldn't.